# React-select custom Option object nor receiving innerprops.key

Tags: react-select

When creating my custom Option object in the react-select, I don't receive the 'key' property of the innerProps object which is required in the doc. https://react-select.com/props#creatable-props > Components > Option. Nevertheless, I receive the rest of properties of innerprops (id, onClick, onMouseOver, tabIndex) and a new onMouseMove. Does anyone have this same problem ?

The object seems to work anyway but I'm afraid of leaving without key for the React reloads.

The custom Option :

```
function Option(props) {
  return (
    <MenuItem
      ref={props.innerRef}
      selected={props.isFocused}
      component="div"
      style={{
        fontWeight: props.isSelected ? 500 : 400,
      }}
      {...props.innerProps}
    >
      {props.children}
    </MenuItem>
  );
}
```